# Store data from a struct on another struct

Tags: c, struct

Im doing something like a supermarket simulator using C. I have a struct that keeps data from hundreds of fictional clients like so:

```
typedef struct clients {
int ID;
char Name[50];
}Clients;
```

I imported a .txt file containing these clients. It basically looks like this:

```
1234 Peter Parker
4724 Barack Obama
3851 John Wick
9428 Donald Trump
...
```

So now I have to simulate a supermarket, i have a timer that updates itself, picking random clients from the struct and put them inside the supermarket, i need to keep track how many of them and which of them are inside the supermarket. The thing is, i don't know how to like put the clients inside the market and store the data of those clients. For example, imagine client A and B enter the supermarket, how do I store those specific clients in the market, so that like i could search which of them are inside the market? Should I make a struct containing data from the struct Clients? I have no idea. Glad if you could help me.

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't it consume a lot of memory cause I would need to be constantly reading the entire struct over and over again looking for those who are inside the market? I was thinking of something more practical for example a struct identical to Clients but containing just the clients who are inside

Comment: @rafaoliveira35 I think it really depends on what you want to do with the data. Are you going to be adding people and removing them from the supermarket a lot? Are you going to be printing their names? Without knowing that its impossible to come to an answer about what is best.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of your clients struct.

Here are some resources I found.
http://www.asic-world.com/scripting/structs_c.html
http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-array-structure/

Comment: Useful information, just didn't find anything specific to my problem

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to use some kind of directed (or bidirected) list containing references to your Client structure. For instance,

```
typedef struct {
  Client *client;
  Visitor *next;
  Visitor *prev;
} Visitor;
```

may be one of the nodes of that list. In the case of head or tail of the list, you can specify NULL values to distinguish different corner cases, but that depends on realization.

The list itself:

```
typedef struct {
    Visitor *head;
    Visitor *tail;
} VisitorList;
```

The drawback of such structure is that getting number of visitors has linear complexity which may be not that you want.

Comment: I actually do have a struct Node exactly like that, I just don't know how that could help me to say which of the clients are not inside the market and which of them are

Comment: why not just add a `bool`, `int`, `enum` to represent that? (in the `client` struct)

Comment: Wouldn't it consume a lot of performance since i would need to be reading the entire struct over and over again looking for which one of them have some kind of variable saying they are inside? I was thinking of something more practical like a struct identical to Clients but containing just the ones who are inside.

Comment: @rafaoliveira35, just list itself can represents people inside. If you have empty list, then your market is empty. By taking the client field and reaching its name, you can receive all demanded info.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there are many ways to do this, with pros and cons to each. If you care about performance and your data gets larger than hundreds and into the upper thousands then you probably start worrying about what type of data structure you're using, which then becomes a question about data structures and how you'll be searching for the names. If you're not so worried about performance, you can go for an array implementation where you create an array of `Clients` like so: which declares an array of 200 clients that you can assign values to.

```
Clients array[200];
```

The down side of this is if you get more `Clients` than you've allocated memory for, you'll have to either `malloc` more memory to fit it.

Alternatively you can go with the linked list implementation and create some sort of `struct` that represents a node with corresponding functions to manipulate it.

```
typedef struct {
  Client *client;
  node *next;
  node *prev;
} node;
```

But this would require writing more code to add and remove nodes at minimum.

So, its really question of what YOU want.

EDIT:
If you just want to add a way of knowing if some client is in the super market why not create an `enum` and add it into the `client` `struct`? I prefer this over bool because then if you want to put someone in another place in the future, then you have the option to just add it to the `enum`.

```
enum place {
    supermarket,
    none
};
```